# Fix a permission disaster Ubuntu Linux in `/` directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I've just spent most of the day setting up an Ubuntu 12.10 server and I was really enjoying it. I was stupid enough to do:

```
sudo chmod 666 /*
```

instead of the equally suspect

```
sudo chmod 666 ./*
```

I can't use any programs on the system now

I havent yet set a root password so now I really wished I was on CentOS :'(

Is there anything I can do without starting again? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for future reference, you never need to use `./*`, the simple `*` will suffice and is less prone to misstypings.

Comment: Having a root user wouldn't have helped in your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to boot from a live cd, because all your executables are not reachable in the moment (dropped access bit on directories `/bin`, ...).

**Please do:**

1. boot from a live cd
2. mount your system below `mnt`, don't forget to add additional mounts like `/usr`, `/var`, ...
3. `cd /mnt/`
4. `for d in * ; do if [ -d ${d} ] ; chmod u+rwx,og+rx-w ${d}; fi`
5. `chmod og= root lost+found # more restrictive permissions`
6. reboot your system and drink a beer :-)

**caveat:**
This applies to the root directory `/` which normally consists only of subdirectories and symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm trying it now. I suppose that's such a logical solution I didn't really think of it!

Comment: @Cobolt - your welcome :-) Be happy and think what would have been happened if you also had added the `-R` switch to `chmod` ;-)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. I think it's time I learnt bash scripting, php/perl doesn't make me thing sys admin enough. Thanks again!